# Setting up OpenVPN for reverse VPN gateway

Tags: ubuntu, openvpn, vpn, aws

So I'm trying to configure an openvpn server to work as a reverse vpn tunnel as explained in [this Hak5 video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b7qr0laM8kA). I'm using an AWS instance, and I have the VPN part working, in that I can tunnel into the VPN server from my laptop and use it as a regular VPN. I already have the client files generated, and now I only need to set up the rest for the reverse VPN part. I'd highly recommend watching the video, because it explains what I want to do better than I can, but in essence I'm building a "dropbox" or a device I'd drop on a network, and when connected to an ethernet port, it would give me access to that network. I'd then tunnel into the vpn server from my laptop, and the vpn server would act as a bridge between the two, allowing the packets to 'flow' from my laptop --> the dropbox.

I'm using a VPN 'road warrior' setup script ([found here](https://github.com/Nyr/openvpn-install)) by Nyr, which configured everything I needed for the normal VPN setup. As a result, my .ovpn files for both my laptop and the dropbox are generated, and would need to be modified manually, unless there is some other way I'm not aware of. They both connect using certificates, but I'm going to list everything I need to do. These are the steps taken in the video through the Access Server UI, but since I don't have that and am rather confused, I'm going to list them here.

I need to:

- Allow auto login on the dropbox device
- For dropbox: Enable VPN Gateway, set ip subnet of client lan or enable for all lans (if possible)
- Allow access from both all server side private subnets and all other VPN clients for the dropbox

If you read through all this, thank you. I appreciate any help I can get, as I've been working on this for over a month now and have been consistently rather stuck. If you need any other info, leave a comment and I'll add it in. Thanks.

Comment: Terminology. You plug a 'backdoor' to the network to get a tunnel that is unforseen/uncontrolled by admins. You plug a 'dropbox' to the network so users there can put (drop) some files into the box.

Comment: I meant dropbox as in a box, or machine, that you 'drop' on a network. It would act as a backdoor into the network, so I suppose it could be either one.

Comment: Why won't you just use the Lan Turtle from Hak5?